# When should I name things with initial capital letters? [r]

Tags: r, naming-conventions

What would be the naming conventions for R?

I've seen some here: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Style.html

In particular, in which cases would you name something in R with **Capital Case**?

Comment: Personally I never use capital case unless I will write the data in a database where the column names are in capital case. Other than that I just use underscore

Comment: I closed it because this is an opinion based question. The dup should answer your question, check out Dirck's and Rasmus' answers.